# remove element from array php

Tags: php, arrays

My first array is like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [column_name] => ben_firstname ) )
```

Second array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [column_name] => ben_unique_id )
        [1] => Array ( [column_name] => ben_firstname )
        [2] => Array ( [column_name] => ben_lastname )
        [3] => Array ( [column_name] => ben_middlename ) )
```

I want to remove ben_firstname (which is in first array) from second array...

I tried with `array_diff` function. But, I am getting error.

CODE:

```
print_r(array_diff($first_array, $second_array));
```

ERROR:

```
 Message: Array to string conversion
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error? Show some code please.

Comment: "I tried with array_diff function." - Show your approach. "But, I am getting error." - What error? Post the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `array_diff` directly because that function expects array elements to be scalar, while in your case they are themselves arrays.

The correct solution is to use [`array_udiff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) with a callback that determines equality by looking at the `column_name` key of each array:

```
$result = array_udiff(
     $second,
     $first, 
     function($x, $y) { return strcmp($x['column_name'], $y['column_name']); }
);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/gR3RF5)**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
$newArray = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

The order is important. What error are you getting?

EDIT: Your error is that you're trying to print an array, not that the array_diff didn't work.

If you want to print a PHP array, print_r should work. What PHP version are you on?